# Find a and b and the position vector of the point of intersection of C of $l_1$ and $l_2$

Tags: calculus, vectors

I asked a similar question to this [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197611/find-a-and-b-given-that-l-1-and-l-2-intersect-at-the-midpoint-of-the-line-se), and I think I managed, however, I have a similar question but a bit different, if I understand this I think I'll manage to confirm the other one as well, so, how would one go about tackling this?

a) The points A and B have position vectors **i**-5**k** and 4**i**+3**j**+**k**, respectively. Find the equation of the line $l_1$ that passes A and B.

Basically, r=a+λ(b-a), which results to: $$i-5k+λ(3i+3j+6k)$$ Correct? or should I put my final answer as: $$i-5k+μ(i+j+2k)$$ Same answer but μ=3λ, would both be correct?

However, my main problem is this;

b) The line $l_2$ with vector question r=6**i**+**j**+a**k**+μ(2**i**+b**j**-**k**) intersects $l_1$ and is perpendicular to it. Find a and b, and the position vector of point of intersection C of $l_1$ and $l_2$.

A guideline on how to achieve it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
In $\vec r=\vec a+\lambda \vec b, \vec b $ is the vector along the line. For two perpendicular vectors, the dot product has to be zero. The point of intersection can simply be solved by equating the i,j and k components of the vectors.